# How to use regEx inside Excel macro to search pattern

Tags: vba, excel

My scenario is to get run a regex pattern that will search across the `Sheet1` (all cells) in my excel file. What I'm want as output is the cell number where that pattern is matching in my `Sheet2` within same excel file. 
With help from lots of questions of stackOverflow and with their answers I managed got how to store result in next sheet. But how should I run my regEx so that it will give result with better performance (my pattern generally will be a string). Code I'm trying now is below :
   
`Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With ws
            For i = 1 To lastrow
                If InStr(Range("B" & i), "Custom ") > 0 Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Range("B" & i).Address
                End If
            Next i
        End With
End Sub`

Comment: You should should state what type of pattern you are looking for as there may be a way that does not require an RE.  To use an RE see [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Comment: @AlexK.Thanks !! I have checked that link... in above code this Range is set for single column I want to search in entire sheet.. if there is any better way to achieve then pls suggest.. my RE is user defined so it can be very simple to complex.